# Examples and/or 3RD Party Libraries to Optimize Display of PDFs on iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have read numerous posts here (and experienced first hand) some of the limitations of using UIWebView to display PDF files on iPad/iPhone.

Are there any 3rd party libraries that handle PDF page rendering/caching/optimization? Don't need to handle adding annotations or markups to the PDF; just want to minimize delays in opening the document and moving between pages in PDFs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using UIWebView use CoreGraphics. The best library I have seen for implementing PDF's with this is the [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) library.

You will need to get familiar with the CGPDF calls and if you are not experienced with CoreGraphics it can be a bit tricky at first but the framework I suggested makes things pretty simple to get started and do basic things like displaying a local document or document on a server.